# translate3d and checkered background

Tags: javascript, html, css, translate3d

I'm implementing a carousel using translate3d for gpu accelerated transitions, I am getting artifacts (white/grey checkered background) on the carousel items. Adding this:

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

to the css of the carousel and moving divs partially solved the problem, but the checkered background is still appearing on the overflowing carousel items.
The ones that are partially visible, not entirely outside the screen, don't get this issue. But when a new item enters the screen, it appears with the strange background before being rendered.

Any hints on how to solve this?